# iOS user authentication (restrict to specific domain name)

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, parse-platform

I'm developing my first iPhone app to make what is effectively an app version of a fantasy league I created for work colleagues.

I am using Parse for the backend of the app.  I only want people to be able to register with their work email address ie only if their e-mail address is **_**@mycompany.com

I'm sure this would be quite easy to someone who knew what htey were doing but I'm kind of new to this so any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in a number of ways. The easiest way would be to have the validation happen on-device - just check the e-mail address the user has put into the app, and only allow the registration to happen if it matches the domain you want to limit it to.

However, although this is very easy it's also open to abuse and it's not very flexible (if you want to add additional domains, you have to update the app).

Fortunately, Parse offers **cloud code**, which lets you validate data server-side. Cloud code is written in JavaScript, and you then upload it to Parse. There is [full documentation on Parse's website](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide), including examples for validating data.